# office 2010 execution file on Windows 8 for decompile

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to decompile an MS Access accde file on a Windows 8.1 machine using [these instructions](http://www.devhut.net/2012/04/16/ms-access-decompile-a-database/)

According to the above, the command I should enter is:
"FullPath\MSACCESS.EXE" "FullPathAndDbNameWithExtension" /decompile

however I cannot find MSACCESS.EXE on my hard disk

should I be using another method?

Comment: Are you sure you have Access installed to begin with? If you have, all you have to do is right-click the icon and have Windows show the correct folder (the exact operation depends on version of Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access won't decompile an ACCDE database.

Decompile discards all the compiled code.  Then compiling the database again regenerates fresh compiled code from the source code.

However, in an ACCDE, all the source code has been removed, leaving only the compiled code.  So in that situation, if you removed the compiled code, there would be no code left.

Fortunately, Access won't cooperate if you try to decompile an ACCDE.  Attempting to do so triggers an error.

You could decompile the original ACCDB which you used to create the ACCDE.  However, that won't have any effect on your existing ACCDE.  You could create a new ACCDE and that will include freshly compiled code regardless of whether or not you first decompile the ACCDB.

If you tell us about the problem you hoped to solve by decompiling your ACCDE, we may be able to offer help.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply.

This ACCDE is a legacy system running on a number of user machines. The system was never intended to be a collaboration platform but now we need to ensure the data these different users are entering are registered into a central location so everyone can read.

Comment: I thought decompiling the ACCDE could give me access to the Tables, and then I would transfer the whole DB into SQL Server and build a new front end.,

Comment: If you create a new ACCDB database, you should then be able to import the tables from your ACCDE into the new database.